# Executable file from Python script can't write to the file

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have a python code that write some outputs to the defined output file in text. In PyCharm, my script works without any problem but when i convert my xx.py to the .exe file by using pyinstaller, exe file can't write to the output file which is already in the same path.

To write the outputs i use this code:

```
fg = open('input.src')
output_file = open("output.obj", "w")
for line in fg:
**do something**
output_file = open("output.obj", "a")
output_file.write("[" + str(hex(memory_location)) + "]" + "  " + output + "\n")
```

I also tried the xx.py without PyCharm, with console, and the script work fine.

Comment: "Can't write" like how? Do you get an error message? Does it just fail silently? What happens when you run the executable?

Comment: @mypetlion, in the code i use 'try: .... except Exception: print("error")' without it, the windows console shut down instantly. otherwise it shows the exception print

Comment: Try this and let me know what the output is: `try: ... except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: @mypetlion  'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 19: invalid start byte. and with this error, i found the problem. i need to change my input encoding to UTF-8. thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mypetlion, the problem was caused by the encoding of the input file which was ANSI. It need to change into UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

> when i convert it to the .exe file ...

It's not clear what conversion process you're referring to.

Definitely PyCharm is running a standard python interpreter as a child process.
It sounds like you may be running cython or other unusual language environment in your problem case.

You wrote:

```
output_file = open("output.obj", "w")
...
output_file = open("output.obj", "a")
```

You chose not to use the `with` idiom.
More importantly, you chose not to `output_file.close()` before re-opening.
Your combination of language interpreter + filesystem may require a close before a subsequent open.